# MSBuild batch task without including metadata value used for batching

Tags: msbuild, batch-file

Is it possible in MSBuild to batch tasks without having the metadata value you are using to bucketize the items appearing in the output?

Let's say I've got the following .proj:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExampColl Include="Item1">
      <Bucket>1</Bucket>
    </ExampColl>
    <ExampColl Include="Item2">
      <Bucket>2</Bucket>
    </ExampColl>
    <ExampColl Include="Item3">
      <Bucket>1</Bucket>
    </ExampColl>
    <ExampColl Include="Item4">
      <Bucket>2</Bucket>
    </ExampColl>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="MyBatch">
    <Message Text="@(ExampColl) in bucket %(Bucket)">
    </Message>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If I run the MyBatch target, I get this output:

```
  Item1;Item3 in bucket 1
  Item2;Item4 in bucket 2
```

What I'm asking is how to batch like this without having the "bucketizer" actually be present in the output, to get output like this:

```
  Item1;Item3 is a batch
  Item2;Item4 is a batch
```

Is this possible? Where would I put the %() or whatever else it is that's needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing in particular, it was more of an academic question. As a matter of fact, I'm working my way through your book and it's great. Thanks!